# How to have hot reload when using "webpack serve" on Webpack 5

Tags: npm, webpack, hot-reload

I just upgraded to Webpack 5, and because `webpack-dev-server` wasn't working anymore, I changed my `npm start` command from `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack serve`.

This is my `npm start` command

```
webpack serve --config  ./build-config/webpack.config.js
```

I can see the console updating, and printing output, but the page in the browser will not update, I have to refresh the browser page.

---

**EXTRA**

Adding `--mode development --env development --hot` to my `npm start` did not fix the problem

webpack version:

```
"webpack": "^5.10.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
```

---

****Note:** I am not talking about webpack-serve**

Comment: how are you accessing the website / project? is it directly localhost:port or are you using nginx or something?

Comment: localport. No nginx

Comment: can you check you browser developer tools -> network tab to see if webpack hot-reload calls are there or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solutions are,

**If you are NOT running off of Node.js**
It's as simple as appending `hot: true` in your `devServer` option of your webpack config.

**If you ARE running off of Node.js**
When creating a webpackDevServer instance in your server file, you have to pass a second *options* argument that contains the key-value pair `hot: true`

The configuration got a bit tricky since Webpack 5 came along. Until I see your dev config/package.json, I will assume you have the correct dependencies/options. It's a bit hard knowing what to take into consideration when answering your question since you didn't provide explicit input on your environment, among other things.

**References**

For documentation/concept:
https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/

For a comprehensive guide:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

Comment: How do you pass that key-value pair?  And how do you know if you’re running off nodejs? Nodejs serves the website on a local host, but I’m a bot confused by what you meant. What would be the situation when you aren’t running off nodejs?

Comment: Basically, are you booting your localhost by running a script (e.g: `node fileName.js` ), or are you using your CLI to run a webpack command? You're running off Node if you answer yes to the first part of the question. That's why seeing your code helps clear it all up.

Comment: I don’t think I’m booting it from a script, I believe npm start just triggers the command “webpack serve”. I can’t share all my code sorry, but I could share certain parts if you name them

Comment: Sure, can you share your webpack.devServer field?

Comment: I’ll have to in the morning, I’m in Canada. I’m guessing you’re in a different timeline

Comment: `devServer: {
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },`

Comment: Append `hot: true,` in there and you should see the following messages in the console  `[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.` and `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS`. When you make changes to your codebase (excluding config files),  you will see something like `[WDS] App hot update...`

Comment: Did that answer your question? If not, let me know if you'd like me to clear something up.

Comment: It did not unfortunately. I updated my question to show what the console is printing out. This happens every time I make a change, so it looks like it's hot reloading, but the browser isn't refreshing

Comment: I also made my script: start command to be `"start": "webpack serve --mode development --env development `

Comment: If you want to take at look at the config files, they're [here](https://github.com/samgermain/react-boiler-plate), this solution works, except hot reload doesn't work when there's an error, and then the error is fixed